# Separation of same layer traces

Tags: voltage, pcb, high-voltage, trace

I've seen this capacitor:
https://api.kemet.com/component-edge/download/datasheet/C0603C221JDGACAUTO.pdf

It is a 0603 capacitor with a 1000VDC rating. As I am familiar with IPC2221, this did not sound right.

As can be seen here: [Minimum clearance between two traces that have a potential difference of 1000VDC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/326517/minimum-clearance-between-two-traces-that-have-a-potential-difference-of-1000vdc)
The separation of two 1000V uncoated conductors should be at least 200mils. 0603 capacitors have only 20 mils separation! How can this be?

Comment: The 0603 capacitors have a rating of 500 volts. Read the data sheet.

Comment: @Andyaka: It's a fair point, but you still wouldn't be able to operate the capacitor at anywhere near its rated voltage.

Comment: Perhaps the OP is (also) asking. In terms of voltage tracking (CTI) and voltage spacing, why have a 1000VDC rating on a 0603 capacitor when the pin-to-pin spacing would violate voltage spacing and/or tracking?

Answer (score 0):

Standards are far from universal.  Some applications require them, others don't. Some engineers use parts up to spec, and others use parts well below maximum ratings.

The sad answer is that when you need to meet some standards, there will be obstacles in your path, and there is no substitute for reading and understanding the standards you need to meet.  Sometimes it becomes important to actually know what you are doing.